# Web service instance configuration (concurrent users) and its performance

Tags: arcgis-server, performance, design, enterprise-architect

I was recently reading about [Server Software Performance](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Server_Software_Performance) and the different settings and recommendations presented by ESRI over their wiki for System Design and architecture strategies. I came across a graph that depicts the [web service instance performance](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Server_Software_Performance#Web_service_instance_configuration_.28concurrent_users.29) based on the multiple incoming requests.

The graph below shows the Display Response Time as Performance in seconds on the left, and the Displays Per Minute (DPM) can be seen on the right side of the graph. One thing it does not show is the Host platform utilization percentage. How can we calculate it?

[image]

The authors mention the percentage usage in the discussion but the graph doesn't seem to show it

Comment: It is not written but it seems that 800 as the upper limit of the scale is considered to mean 100% load.

Comment: This is a sentence from the article explaining the graph:

`The first bar represents a service configuration with two (2) service instances. Peak service load is limited to less than 38 percent host platform utilization with a peak throughput of 287 DPM and display response time just over 0.40 seconds, well below the maximum host platform throughput capacity.`

It confusing as to how did they came up with the host utilization percentage of 38%